# asp.net datagrid borders appear different (bad) in other browsers

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, gridview, google-chrome

Hey, I realize that pages are just going to look different in varying browsers, but mine is looking awesome in Chrome, ok in mozilla, and pretty bad in IE 7.

Sadly, most people using my page will use IE.

My issue is with the borders. I have a redish border around the rows of the grid. In chrome they all appear as they should. In Firefox the bottom and top of each row are working, as well as the right and left of the outside columns, but all the inner columns do not have vertical borders.

In IE, all the borders are missing. There are simply white gaps between my columns and rows.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or tricks you guys could toss my way.

EDIT:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="ProductsGrid" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="323px" 
        style="margin-top: 23px; margin-left: 0px;" BackColor="White" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="4"
        Width="1210px" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"
        onrowdatabound="ProductsGridView_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="25">

        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="Gray" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#330099" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#6E1414" 
            BorderWidth="1px" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `GridLines` property to your `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductsGrid" runat="server" GridLines="None" ...
```

You can set the proprety to `None`, `Both`, `Horizontal`, or `Vertical`. You should be able to get it work as you intend in using the `GridLines` property.

**EDIT:** I think I have it working as you require. Try the following:

Create a CSS style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .yourRowStyle td
    {
        border: solid 1px #6E1414;
    }
</style>
```

Then in your replace your `RowStyle` with:

```
<RowStyle CssClass="yourRowStyle" ForeColor="#330099" BackColor="White" />
```

Also make sure to have your `GridView` set with `GridLines="None"`.

I tested it and this should work although I am not exactly sure what you want it to look like.  You can  Css will override the `GridView`s quirks.

Comment: I appreciate the response and I have been playing around with the GridLines property, but I am still having an issue with IE. If I turn the GridLines to none, there are no borders at all in IE. If it set it to both, the borders are white.

I have tried both of these settings while setting the borders in my .net and in c# (using the databind of the datagrid) and am having the same issue. Any other tips or things I might be missing?

Again, thanks. I will keep working with this property.

Comment: @PFranchise updated my answer.  I have tested it and it should solve your issue in IE7 specifically.  I use IE so I used the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` tag to emulate IE7.  Hopefully the real IE7 works the same way.

Comment: @PFranchise glad I could help. This frusterated me in the past so I know exactly what you were going through and I had to just remember how I had fixed it.